# Python repr/str NoneType has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, repr

Hi I have recently encountered some weird thing. I have the following class:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []

    def __str__(self):
        string = "---- TreeNode Object ---- \n" + \
            "name: {} \n".format(self.name) + \
            "parent: {} \n".format(self.parent.name) + \
            "number of children: {} \n".format(len(self.children))
        return string
```

Now I have a dict of instances stored in *tmp*, with the key the name of the instance, and somehow it has the following behavior

```
print(tmp["650"].name)
>>> 650
try:
    print(tmp["650"])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
>>> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

This only happens to one instance of the dict with all the rest works just fine. I initialized all the instances the same way so this really confuse me.

```
print(tmp["632"].name)
>>> 632
try:
    print(tmp["632"])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
>>> ---- TreeNode Object ---- 
>>> Name: 632 
>>> parent: 650 
>>> number of children: 3
```

I tried to search but there seems to be very few information on NoneType exception with str/repr. Thanks for reading and let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your `TreeNode` instance has `None` as `parent` attribute. In this case, you are trying to recover `None.name`, which does not exist.

To handle nodes without parents, you should account for this in your `__str__` method by replacing...

```
"parent: {} \n".format(self.parent.name)
```

by...

```
"parent: {} \n".format(self.parent.name if self.parent else None)
```

#### Example

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []

    def __str__(self):
        string = "---- TreeNode Object ---- \n" + \
            "name: {} \n".format(self.name) + \
            "parent: {} \n".format(self.parent.name if self.parent else None) + \
            "number of children: {} \n".format(len(self.children))
        return string
```

#### Output

```
>>> print(TreeNode('foo', None))
---- TreeNode Object ---- 
name: foo
parent: None 
number of children: 0
```

Comment: Good catch! Indeed that is the issue! Thank you!